# Bitbake - How to run do_install_prepend() for single machine conf

Tags: bitbake

I have a bb file with following functions. 
`do_install_prepend()` is for default/base machine configuration.
`do_install_prepend_m1()` is for m1 machine configuration.
`do_install_prepend_m2()` is for m2 machine configuration.
`do_install_prepend_m3()` is for m3 machine configuration.

m1 is derived from default configuration. m2 and m3 are derived from m1.

When I run bb file for m3 machine configuration, I see, it runs `do_install_prepend_m3()`, `do_install_prepend_m1()` and `do_install_prepend()`. All 3 functions are called.

Is there a way to modify this bb, so that, only `do_install_prepend_m3()` is run? If `do_install_prepend_m3()` is not present, then it should run `do_install_prepend_m1()`.
If that is not present, it should run `do_install_prepend()`. That is, I only want to run one function.

```
do_install_prepend () {
    echo "default install_prepend"
}

do_install_prepend_m1 () {
    echo "m1 install_prepend"
}

do_install_prepend_m2 () {
    echo "m2 install_prepend"
}

do_install_prepend_m3 () {
    echo "m3 install_prepend"
}
```

Thanks for your help.